# customizing the Antisamy policy xml to allow more html and grails tags

Tags: xml, grails, policy, antisamy

I am using the sanitizer plugin in grails and it internally uses the antisamy policy xml to apply sanitization rules to ui input.
The policy xml I have selected is antisamy-myspace.xml which filters javascript tags and code and the < html > and < body >  and < head > tags.

The problem is its also rejecting some grails tags particularly the following 2:

```
1) <g:formatDate date="${frmDateStr}" format="EEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"/>

2) <g:each in="${resourcelist}" var="resourceid"> some content here..</g:each>
```

These two tags do not pass the validation, I need to make them pass or allowable through the validator, also I want to allow the < html > and < body >  and < head > tags.

How do I modify the antisamy policy file to allow these tags?\
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, I just did some more research on the above tags and the problem is "<g" is not allowed? the crude option right now i am thinking is include a space between '<' and 'g' for all such tags and then after validation again remove the space.. or is there a way I can allow this using a regex from the xml?

Comment: You may want to give a look to http://grails.org/plugin/html-cleaner as  well, it provides a simple to use DSL to define tag whitelists

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the antisamy-anythinggoes sanitizer policy file, and then just trace all the bits for an known tag.  From a quick browse, it looks like you'll need entries in tag-rules, and make sure to specify the attributes.  You will have to define the reg expressions to catch those values as well.  More about Antisamy can be found [here].[1](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project#tab=How_do_I_get_started_3F)